# Concatenar arquivos csv grandes python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook

estou tentando concatenar arquivos que chegam a uma soma de 650MB, e está retornando erro de memória:

```
> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 70.3 MiB for an array with shape (3, 6143249) and data type object
```

linha que estou usando para concatenar:

```
li # lista dos arquivos
df = pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```

existe outra forma de concatenar arquivos grandes?
obrigado

Comment: é uma tarefa que se repetirá várias vezes? se não, use o shell `cp a.txt b.txt c.txt tudo_junto.txt` ou sendo windows, use: "copy a.txt b.txt c.txt tudo_junto.txt"

Comment: @PauloMarques Na verdade, no Unix/Linux tem que usar `cat` (e não `cp`): `cat a.txt b.txt c.txt > tudo_junto.txt` - e no Windows é  `copy a.txt+b.txt+c.txt tudo_junto.txt` (faltou o `+` entre os arquivos)

Comment: @Saulo a solução para o seu caso é utilizar chunks. Ao que me parece, um problema nos seus arquivos é que tem muitas colunas, então os chunks devem ser aplicados às colunas, veja essa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727671/pandas-column-wise-chunking

Comment: @hkotsubo, obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vou listar algumas coisas que eu sei que você pode tentar fazer ou até mesmo combinar várias delas e sei que existem muitas outras. Antes de tudo garanta que você tem a última versão do pandas.

**Importando CSV - definindo dtype:** A primeira coisa que você tem que ter em mente é que sempre que você carrega um arquivo pra um `DataFrame` do pandas ele vai tentar adivinhar o tipo de dado do seu CSV e isso é ruim porque enquanto ele faz isso ele precisa manter todos os dados do arquivo como objetos (strings) na memória. Se você informa pro pandas qual o tipo de dado de cada coluna ele não precisa fazer isso e você economiza muita memória. Para definir o tipo de dados do seu CSV use `dtype={'coluna':tipo}` como parâmetro do `read_csv()`. Só tenha em mente que se você tiver dados corrompidos (uma string em uma coluna que deveria conter apenas números) o `read_csv()` vai dar erro.

**Se for concatenar vários arquivos, faça aos poucos:** você não quer e nem precisa de vários `DataFrames` carregados simultaneamente, prefira fazer a concatenação de dois em dois livrando os que já foram concatenados na memória. Exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
del df2
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df3])
del df3
```

**Salvar os DataFrames em um único CSV é melhor do que concatenar:** se a memória é um problema, use o seu HD. Abra cada arquivo de uma vez e salve em um csv usando `mode='a'. Veja um exemplo:

```
df1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
df2.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', columns=False, index=False)
df3.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', columns=False, index=False)
```

**Não use o pandas se você não precisar:** se você quer concatenar arquivos e não precisa mexer neles, não perca tempo importando os arquivos como `DataFrames` para depois concatenar. Use um comando bash ou faça no python:

```
def concat(file1, file2):
    with open(file2, 'r') as filename2:
        data = file2.read()
    with open(file1, 'a') as filename1:
        file.write(data)

concat('file.csv', 'file1.csv')
concat('file.csv', 'file2.csv')
concat('file.csv', 'file3.csv')
```

**Não use CSV:** essa talvez seja, de todas, a questão mais ousada, porém, muitas vezes é a solução salvadora. Arquivos CSV são de lenta manipulação porque fazem conversão de dados em modo de texto. Uma solução em HDF5 é muito mais eficiente porque faz a conversão de dados em modo binário.